# Error Internal Server 500 xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );

Tags: javascript, controller

Buenas.

Tengo un proceso de Javascript que hace una llamada POST a un controller, y estoy recibiendo error Internal Server 500 , y en jquery me marca esta linea

```
 xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
```

Esto solo pasa si devuelvo datos vacios desde el controller. Si realiza el proceso correcto no sale ese error.
El problema es que es una llamada continua a ese controller y se me llena la consola de mensajes de error, aunque el funcionamiento del programa es correcto.

Os dejo el codigo de javascript y del controller.

```
function getMessagesUser(e) {

    //Una vez cargada la página pinto el historial de mensajes de esa conversación.
    var values = {
        "userID": "11",
        "appID": "22"
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: urlControl + "/GetMessages",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: values,
        success: function (msgsUser) {
            if (msgsUser != null && msgsUser != "") {
                for (x = 0; x < msgsUser.length; x++) {
                  //Realizo la acción
                }
            }
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            console.log(errMsg);
        } 
    });


    var timer = setTimeout(getMessagesUser, 5000);
}
```

El controller

```
[HttpPost("GetMessages")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetMessages([FromServices] IChat AC)
    {

        //Busco mensajes pendientes para ese usuario
        List<MessageUser> listMsg = await AC.GetMessagesPending();
        var resultMsg = listMsg;//Hago copia de la lista que se va a enviar


        if (resultMsg != null)
        {
            return Json(resultMsg);

        }

        return Json(String.Empty);
    }
```

Si hay datos los devuelve correctamente y los pinta bien en pantalla, pero si no hay mensajes que devolver, por cada llamada que realiza el javascript me aparecer ese mensaje.

¿Puede ayudarme por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a modificar tu controlador para, en lugar de enviar una cadena vacía, mandes un *objeto* vacío:

```
return Json(new { }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

La razón puede ser que la llamada espera un JSON (en tu script lo especificas en `dataType: "json"`) y al devolver desde el controlador una cadena vacía, lo que recibe es un JSON inválido (`""`) cuando debería recibir un Json vacío (`{}`).

Hablando del error específico que te está dando se debe a esto:

> Al procesar la respuesta del servidor, `xhr` (la biblioteca que maneja las llamadas asíncronas) prepara un objeto `options` con, entre otros campos, un bool llamado `hasContent` y un objeto `data` que contiene la respuesta del servidor.

Al ocurrir un error al parsear el JSON dentro de `data`, este último queda como `undefined` o `null`. Como `hasContent` es verdadero, al entrar en la comparación `&&` intentará trabajar con `data` pero al ser este *no definido* genera el error. Si `hasContent` es falso (como ocurriría con un objeto vacío) simplemente pasa al otro lado del operador `||` y seguiría con null sin dar ningún error.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. Al final era cuestión de encerrar el código dentro de un try catch y ver que la evaluación del null generaba un error, que era el que devolvia al navegador. Error de principiante, pero tu respuesta me ha servido para darme cuenta.